# How can I see Eclipse compilation details log

Tags: eclipse, performance, compilation

Is it possible to see Eclipse compilation details logs?

After a number of project changes, the compilation speed became very low (~10 seconds after a simple file change). Whould be nice to see, what compilation steps take most time.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [debug trace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility%3F) for JDT/Core plugin. See more details in [this post](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jdt-core-dev/msg00004.html) as well as in the .options file in org.eclipse.jdt.core plugin.